# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.assignment.controller.CRUDController

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classnotfoundexception

[Picure Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K62gm.png)

NOTE: in the picture above it says the packages names are assignmentdan and in the problem "dan" is not there but that in no way affects this error!

when deploying my Eclipse app to AWS which runs on TOMCAT8 , it wouldnt display my SQL database. I checked the logs and there was this exception:

```
05-Apr-2016 13:57:23.975 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet CRUDController as unavailable
05-Apr-2016 13:57:23.978 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet CRUDController

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.assignment.controller.CRUDController
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means about my Servlet? Everything seems in order??

CRUDController ( where i create my servlet)

```
public class CRUDController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CrudDao dao;

    public CRUDController() {
        dao=new CrudDao();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getParameter("action")!=null){
            List<User> lstUser=new ArrayList<User>();
            String action=(String)request.getParameter("action");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            response.setContentType("application/json");

            if(action.equals("list")){
                try{                        
                //Fetch Data from User Table
                lstUser=dao.getAllUsers();          
                //Convert Java Object to Json               
                JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(lstUser, new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType());
                JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                String listData=jsonArray.toString();               
                //Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
                listData="{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":"+listData+"}";            
                response.getWriter().print(listData);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getMessage()+"}";
                    response.getWriter().print(error);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            else if(action.equals("create") || action.equals("update")){
                User user=new User();
                if(request.getParameter("userid")!=null){                  
                   int userid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
                   user.setUserid(userid);
                }
                if(request.getParameter("firstName")!=null){
                    String firstname=(String)request.getParameter("firstName");
                    user.setFirstName(firstname);
                }
                if(request.getParameter("lastName")!=null){
                   String lastname=(String)request.getParameter("lastName");
                   user.setLastName(lastname);
                }
                if(request.getParameter("email")!=null){
                   String email=(String)request.getParameter("email");
                   user.setEmail(email);
                }
                try{                                            
                    if(action.equals("create")){//Create new record
                        dao.addUser(user);                  
                        lstUser.add(user);
                        //Convert Java Object to Json               
                        String json=gson.toJson(user);                  
                        //Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
                        String listData="{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Record\":"+json+"}";                                          
                        response.getWriter().print(listData);
                    }else if(action.equals("update")){//Update existing record
                        dao.updateUser(user);
                        String listData="{\"Result\":\"OK\"}";                                  
                        response.getWriter().print(listData);
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                        String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getStackTrace().toString()+"}";
                        response.getWriter().print(error);
                }
            }else if(action.equals("delete")){//Delete record
                try{
                    if(request.getParameter("userid")!=null){
                        String userid=(String)request.getParameter("userid");
                        dao.deleteUser(Integer.parseInt(userid));
                        String listData="{\"Result\":\"OK\"}";                              
                        response.getWriter().print(listData);
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getStackTrace().toString()+"}";
                response.getWriter().print(error);
            }               
        }
     }
  }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_0.xsd"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>main.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>main.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <servlet>
        <display-name>CRUDController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>CRUDController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.assignment.controller.CRUDController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CRUDController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CRUDController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>AssignmentDan</groupId>
 <artifactId>AssignmentDan</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <build>
   <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: What is the package name of the `CRUDController` class?

Comment: @cricket_007  
com.assignment.controller.CRUDController

Comment: @Leanneheal, Can you please post your project structure as an image and also please post your pom.xml file if you maintain any?

Comment: Just making sure because you didn't copy the `package com.assignment.controller` line into the question.

Comment: As always, when having a `ClassNotFoundException`, check your **classpath**. Is the JAR, which contains `com.assignment.controller.CRUDController`, really on the classpath?

Comment: @PraveenKumar updated!

Comment: @BalusC no sorry I shouldve said i said before i posted pic dan to every assignment so now its com.assignmentdan.controller.CRUDController...it doesnt effect anything tho i still have the same errors

Comment: @Ben yes im sure they are added on the classpath they have been added to WebContent/Web-INF/libs

Comment: Are you really sure that com.**assignment**.controller.CRUDController is correct? maybe you mean: com.**assignmentdan**.controller.CRUDController? (check the **packagename**)

Comment: i realise thats not my problem i changed the package name one tiny bit.. if u dont know the problem and are just pointing out obvious points can u not comment on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I read. But in your pic you have **com.assignmentdan** and in your web.xml you have **com.assignment** (without **dan**)

Comment: i know and i commented and said i changed everywhere it says assignment.. it assignementdan.

Comment: `i know and i commented and said...` so why don't you update your question? How to find out the reason of your problem when the posted code/xml/picture does not match your **real** code environment anymore. In your posted **web.xml** is still **com.assignment** to read. `if u dont know the problem...can u not comment on this problem` I just tried to help. You are very unpolite.

Answer (score 0):

> ClassNotFoundException: com.assignment.controller.CRUDController

Just look at your package structure.

You have no package with the name `com.assignment.controller`. You instead have a package by the name of `com.assignmentdan.controller`.

Let's go through the comments...

> i posted pic dan to every assignment so now its com.assignmentdan.controller.CRUDController...it doesnt effect anything tho i still have the same errors
>
> i changed the package name one tiny bit
>
> i changed everywhere it says assignment.. it assignementdan

@Ben already told you the solution, but you didn't seem to understand. Since you changed the package name to `com.assignmentdan` you must manually edit the `web.xml` file to reflect that change.

```
<servlet-class>com.assignmentdan.controller.CRUDController</servlet-class>
```

Additionally, I think in the `pom.xml`, the groupId should be `com.assignmentdan.controller`

Comment: i actually need to write a new question maybe or upload a new xml because i realise that.. i updated the web.xml to <servlet-class>com.assignmentdan.controller.CRUDController</servlet-class> and got the exact same error saying that it cant find my servlet

Comment: I added one more thing in the answer. Maybe try maven clean and build again. I don't think you should be getting the same error after you update that file.